# Frontend ACF checkboxes not updating in admin on save

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have a checkbox created using ACF in my product admin page. I have successfully added these checkboxes to the frontend but they are not updating when the vendor saves the form.

Here is my custom checkbox information...

**field meta name:** _personal_options
**Array options:** 
name: Name
message: Message
**Field key:** field_5b54938f699a9

Here is my code that I added to the frontend product edit page/form

```
<div class="dokan-form-group">                                     
<label>
<input name="fields[field_5b54938f699a9][]" type="checkbox" id="acf-field-_personal_options" class="<?php echo 'id_' . $store_id; ?>" value="name" <?php checked('name', get_user_meta($store_id, 'acf-field-_personal_options', true), $echo = true) ?>/><?php _e('Enable gift name option', 'dokan');?>
</label>
</div>

<div class="dokan-form-group">
<label>
<input name="fields[field_5b54938f699a9][]" type="checkbox" id="acf-field-_personal_options-message" class="<?php echo 'id_' . $store_id; ?>" value="message" <?php checked('message', get_user_meta($store_id, 'acf-field-_personal_options-message', true), $echo = true) ?>/><?php _e('Enable gift message option', 'dokan');?>                                      
</label>
</div>
```

I have managed to get normal text fields to work fine but struggling with checkboxes. Here is my working text fields:

```
<label for="_personal_name_field" class="form-label">Gift name</label>
<?php dokan_post_input_box( $post_id, '_personal_name_field', array( 'placeholder' => 'Enter name...' ) ); ?> 

<label for="_personal_message_field" class="form-label">Gift message</label>
<?php dokan_post_input_box( $post_id, '_personal_message_field', array( 'placeholder' => 'Enter message...' ), 'textarea' ); ?>
```

Really really need help with this.

Comment: The text fields that work above still populate ACF fields. The dokan form uses checkboxes also to update other woocommerce settings such as downloadable products options.

Comment: <div class="content-half-part downloadable-checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" <?php checked( $is_downloadable, true ); ?> class="_is_downloadable" name="_downloadable" id="_downloadable"> <?php _e( 'Downloadable', 'dokan-lite' ); ?> <i class="fa fa-question-circle tips" aria-hidden="true" data-title="<?php _e( 'Downloadable products give access to a file upon purchase.', 'dokan-lite' ); ?>"></i>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>

Comment: So surely I must be able to utilise one of these the same as I did the text fields. I have managed to add those fields values to the cart and checkout and email etc. Its just the saving of the custom checkbox.

Comment: Any thoughts or help?